# Seting style in constructor of dynamically created widget doesn't work

Tags: android, android-widget, android-button, android-resources

I'm trying to dynamically create an `ImageButton` and apply a style to it.

Here is my style:

```
<style name="ActionBarActionButton">
    <item name="android:layout_width">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_button</item>
</style>
```

And here is button creation:

```
ImageButton actionButton = new ImageButton(context, null, R.style.ActionBarActionButton);
```

It seems to has no effect at all, non of the styles params are applied.

Answer (score 2):

I found into that this way doesn't work, but nobody could told why (hello google?)

I had to use such workarround:

**I've crated a new layout file for button:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/action_button" >
</ImageButton>
```

**And then inflated it into layout like this:**

```
    LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ImageButton actionButton = (ImageButton) inflater.inflate(R.layout.imagebutton_action, getActionsLayout(), false);
    actionButton.setImageResource(action.getIconResource());        
    getActionsLayout().addView(actionButton);
```